# Express.js (ejs 使用) で、外部のデータベース(MySQL)のテーブル一覧を表示する方法

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js

Express.js で外部にあるデータベースのテーブル情報をやりとりするための具体的なコードが分かりません。
例えば、テーブルの一覧を表示するコードはどうなりますか？

**課題となっているところ**

1. `all.js` において `app.get('/', function (request, response, next) { res.render('all', ...)})` で `all.ejs` を投げることと
2. 

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '??',
  user: '?',
  password: '',
  database: 'dbname'
});
```

（ `app.js` と `all.js` どちらに記載すべき？）
➝

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT...', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err
 // この辺りの記述も分からない
}); // query の記述
```

と記述するのだが、1. とどう組み合わせるのか。

3. ejs の変数も投げる必要があります（後述）。

**追記**
・top page から `./all/` というページにとんだら一覧が表示される、という状況でお願いします。
・ mysql は外部にあります（`const connection = mysql.createConnection({});` の `{}`内 `host` に書くIPアドレスを localhost にしてしまうと、 mysql の場所の指定はどこでするのでしょうか？？）。MySQL 側でこの webサーバがある IPアドレスを指定して（ IPアドレスとユーザに権限を与えて）こちらは localhost でよいということでしょうか。(その場合ですと MySQL の場所の情報ってないですよね？)
・view engine に ejs を用いているので、その前提でお願いします。

**テーブル(MySQL)**
[image: データ構造]
全部で 200強 rows あります。

**`all.ejs`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title><%=title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/all.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><%=title %></h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="top">
    <div>
      <div><a href=<%= top %>>Topへ戻る</a></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="output">
    <div>
      <p>一覧の表示</p>
      <table>
        <%- content %>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      <p><%= libraryName %></p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

`res.render` で `title, top, libraryName, content` も投げる必要があります。

**ファイル構成**
`index.ejs` で `top.css` を読み込んでいます.
一覧を表示する `./routes/all.js` のコーディングに苦戦しています.

[image: ファイル構成]

Comment: 追記分拝見しましたが、テーブルのデータ構造がないとejsで表示することすらできないです。また、追記の内容によって質問の本質が大きく変わっていますので、別の質問に切り分けることをおすすめします。

Comment: テーブルの情報を追記しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ejsにデータを渡す

expressでejsを使う場合は、テンプレート側(.ejsファイル)で使用する変数(all.ejsの場合だとtitleやtopなど)をrenderメソッドの第２引数に指定します。
形式はテンプレート側で使う変数名をキーにしたオブジェクトで、all.ejsの場合だとこのようになるでしょう。

```js
app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
  res.render('all', {
    title: '一覧ページ',
    top: '/',
    libraryName: '',
    content: '<tr><td>データ</td></tr>'
  })
})
```

2. MySQLへの接続、クエリ

読み込み順序やサーバーを起動したときにデータベースに接続するために、db.jsなど別ファイルに書くのが良いと思います。

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: ''
})

module.exports = connection
```

hostやuserなどは接続先のデータベースの情報を入れます。
localhostは自身を指すので、具体的な状況は分からないですが、異なるサーバーで実行されているのならば、そのサーバーのホスト名やIPアドレスを入れることになります。

all.jsからのqueryはこのようになります。

```js
const connection = require('../db')

app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM books', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    let table = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      table += '<tr>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].id + '</td>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].title + '</td>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].author + '</td>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].genre + '</td>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].hight + '</td>'
      table += '<td>' + rows[i].publisher + '</td>'
      table += '</tr>'
    }

    res.render('all', {
      title: '一覧ページ',
      top: '/',
      libraryName: '...',
      content: table
    })
  })
})
```

rowsにはその名前の通り、データベースから取得した行の配列が入っているので、これを元に表示するHTMLを生成して渡します。

ここまでall.ejsに`<%- content %>`とあったのでall.js側でHTMLを生成し埋め込むという想定でここまで書きましたが、ejs側でテーブル構造を表現(HTMLを生成)するのが良いでしょう。
これはHTMLを生成する部分と、プログラムの処理を分けることで可読性や保守性が上がるほか、HTMLに意図しないデータが含まれてしまうのを防ぐことができます。
もしユーザーによってデータベースに値を追加される場合、`<script>alert('XSS!')</script>`のような文字列を入れられた場合、そのままHTMLに埋め込まれ表示してしまいます。これはXSS脆弱性です。
テンプレート側でテーブル構造を表現することでこの問題を回避することができます。

```
<table>
  <% for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= books[i].id %></td>
      <td><%= books[i].title %></td>
      <td><%= books[i].author %></td>
      <td><%= books[i].genre %></td>
      <td><%= books[i].hight %></td>
      <td><%= books[i].publisher %></td>
    </tr>    
  <% } %>
</table>
```

このように書くことで、`<%- foo %>`を使ったHTMLの埋め込みをさけ、`<%= foo %>`を使うことができるため、XSS脆弱性が発生しません。

all.jsからはHTML生成処理がなくなるので、単にrowsを渡すだけになります。

```js
const connection = require('../db')

app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM books', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err

    res.render('all', {
      title: '一覧ページ',
      top: '/',
      libraryName: '...',
      content: rows
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### 直接的な実装

直接クエリを叩く最もシンプルな形だと次のようになります。

```sh
# expressとmysql2をインストールする
npm i express mysql2
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

async function getTableData() {
  // データベースへの接続を確立させる ここは自分のデータベースに合わせてください。
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "userName",
    database: "databaseName",
    password: "raw password", // 取り扱い注意
  });
  // SQLを実行 ここは自分のデータベースに合わせてください。
  const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM [tableName]");

  return {
    rows,
    fields,
  };
}

// expressサーバーを作成
const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getTableData();
  const html = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`;
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("http://localhost:3000");
});
```

```sh
# サーバーを起動
node server.js
```

`http://localhost:3000` に接続すると、DBから取得したデータが一覧で表示されます。

### O/R Mapperが必要な場合

いまだとTypeORMあたりでしょうか。mysql2をラップして作成されたものです。スキーマの定義からする必要があるので、ドキュメントを読んでみると良いでしょう。

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm

### 参考

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper

Comment: view engine に ejs を用いていたらどうなりますか？

Answer (score 0):

これは MySQL 側の問題で、データベースの user に [username]@[IP address] と登録（create）するとき、IPアドレスにサーバの場所ではなく MySQL の場所を登録することが必要で、（最初）違和感でした。